# Ubuntu 12.04 PHP5.3 opcache.so installtion problem

Tags: 12.04, php

I got this error when i call `php -v`

```
Failed loading opcache.so:  opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:27:25)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Anybody has a solution to fix this problem?! I can't find something on the the net!!!

Answer (score 1):

opcache.ini

`zend_extension=opcache.so` -> `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/opcache.so`

Fixed it for me on Ubuntu 12.04, PHP5.4